# Why does Pascal Script expect another semicolon near my external-function declaration?

Tags: c++, dll, pascalscript

I have written a function in C++, making a DLL:

functions.h:

```c++
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H


int DLLsquare(int x);
#endif  /* FUNCTIONS_H */
```

functions.cpp:

```c++
#include "functions.h"
int DLLsquare(int x){
    return x*x;
}
```

I compiled this to a DLL. Now I would like to import this into Pascal Script:

```pascal
program TestDLL;

function Square(x: Integer): Integer;
external 'DLLsquare@libTestDLL.dll';

begin
end.
```

Now this doesn't compile. I get:

> (7:1): Semicolon (';') expected at line 6
>   Compiling failed.

Several tutorials on the internet tell me that this is exactly the way to go, so what am I missing here?

Comment: are you missing  semicolon anywhere else then did you checked it

Comment: Which Pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes, i tried adding and removing semicolons at all kinds of places, but in my experience the syntax is correct this way. Unless I'm missing something here, which I clearly do :)

Comment: @RobKennedy It is PascalScript, does that provide enough info?

Comment: Yes. That's a very important distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal Script will throw a "semicolon expected" error if you declare an external function and don't have a handler assigned to the `OnExternalProc` event.

You can implement it yourself, or you can use `DllExternalProc` from the *uPSC_dll* unit. Consider calling `RegisterDll_Compiletime` on your compiler component, which assigns the `OnExternalProc` event and registers two functions for your scripts to call, `UnloadDll` and `DLLGetLastError`.

Although it's understandable to raise an error when the host program has provided no means of handling external functions, the specific wording of the error message is nonsense. I encourage you to [file an issue](https://github.com/remobjects/pascalscript/issues/new) with the project to get it improved.